# covert two scala.collection.Iterable's into a Java List or Iterator

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I've two `scala.collection.Iterable` that I'd like to convert to a `java.util.List` or something more efficient in Java 8 Collections. What is the efficient way? I am new to Scala and I found [JavaConversions](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConversions$) but I am trying to understand what is the efficient way to do it as I've to do this for over half a billion items to process in Apache Spark.

**Context**

I've Java API that takes a List (or I can change the API to whatever you suggest) and iterates through all of the items (order doesnt matter) to create a single result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you iterate just once in java, java's `Iterable` should do fine here.
It should be fairly fast, because implementation of conversion looks like this (very simple wrapper):

```
trait IterableWrapperTrait[A] extends ju.AbstractCollection[A] {
  val underlying: Iterable[A]
  def size = underlying.size
  override def iterator = IteratorWrapper(underlying.iterator)
  override def isEmpty = underlying.isEmpty
}

case class IteratorWrapper[A](underlying: Iterator[A]) extends ju.Iterator[A] with ju.Enumeration[A] {
  def hasNext = underlying.hasNext
  def next() = underlying.next()
  def hasMoreElements = underlying.hasNext
  def nextElement() = underlying.next()
  def remove() = throw new UnsupportedOperationException
}
```

To use that you need to import

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
```

and call `asJava` method on your scala `Iterable`. Or you can take an iterator and do the same for it, shouldn't matter.

A small note on `JavaConverters` vs `JavaConversions`. The first one requires you to explicitly call `asScala` and `asJava` on your collection which is considered more readable, while latter uses implicit conversion that can become cryptic to someone who has to read it.

**Edit**

I am not sure if I understood you correctly but I think you might want to merge two iterables first and then pass them to java?

If so you can use iterators:

```
val c1: Iterable[Int] = ???
val c2: Iterable[Int] = ???
val merged: Iterator[Int] = Iterator(c1.iterator, c2.iterator).flatten
val javaVersion: java.util.Iterator[Int] = merged.asJava
```

Comment: is there a way to concatenate two iterables into 1?

Comment: I just realized that you might want that and I added answer. This is very efficient way without copying any elements.